# Organizational Forms Library Subfolder in Oultook

Tags: exchange, outlook, public-folders

How can I create a subfolder within the Outlook Organization Forms Library?

I have been able to publish forms to this location, but I would like to create a folder and have additional forms published to this subfolder. Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1):

Wow...that takes me back.  I'm actually a little shocked to see people using this still after years of Sharepoint/Infopath being around.

Regardless...I'm pretty certain what you are asking cannot be done, creating subfolders within the Organizational Forms Library.  You could publish a form to a specific Public folder instead of the Library but often you are wanting a mail form so that wouldn't work in that instance.

Comment: Thanks. I thought I would give it a shot. I was not sure if it was even possible! :/